# Optical Character Recognition for protractor

Tags: typescript, webdriver, protractor, ocr

Is way to get text from image using protractor? something like Optical Character Recognition from automation tests?

Comment: I don't believe there is any package with built in OCR that directly works with protractor. However, you could use the [screenshot](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.takeScreenshot) function, and then send it off to a non protractor function.

Comment: Ben, it can be a solution.